# LMEM for low number of data points?

Tags: regression, linear, sequence-analysis

I have DNA and RNA counts of 4 time points with 4 replicates. I want to quantitate the change in RNA copy number relative to DNA copy number for each gene in the genome. I especially interested to test if there is a linear relationship between these two. I am thinking of using linear mixed effect regression model to account for the replicates.

I am concerned that I have too few data points for calculating a slope and R squared.
Are there any alternatives to study the DNA-RNA relationship and also account for the inter-replicate variability that I can try? Or is it okay to go ahead with linear mixed effect models?